# making KvmSerializable object to request SOAP service

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I just want to request SOAP service from ***android*** and I am passing the data with the help of [KvmSerializable](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/KvmSerializable.html) object.

I am doing it perfectly with this reference [link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html) when I want to send simple data such as in Case 1.

But when I want to send complex data to SOAP service I am not knowing how to form KvmSerializable object such as in Case 2. I got some ref [link](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives) but unable to solve it.

### **Case 1:**

*data to send:*

```
<UserDetails>
   <name>string</name>
   <reportitem>string</reportitem>
   <reportid>long</reportid>  
</UserDetails>
```

*KvmSerializable class which I have written:*

```
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class UserDetails implements KvmSerializable {

private String name;
private String reportitem;
private String reportid;

public static final int NAME = 0;
public static final int REPORT_ITEM = NAME + 1;
public static final int REPORT_ID = REPORT_ITEM + 1;
public static final int PARAM_COUNT = REPORT_ID + 1;

@Override
public Object getProperty(int param_pos) {

    switch (param_pos) {
        case NAME:
            return name;

        case REPORT_ITEM:
            return reportitem;

        case REPORT_ID:
            return reportid;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return PARAM_COUNT;
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int param_pos, Object val) {

    switch (param_pos) {
        case NAME:
            name = Long.parseLong(val.toString());
            break;

        case REPORT_ITEM:
            reportitem = val.toString();
            break;

        case REPORT_ID:
            reportid = val.toString();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int param_pos, Hashtable hashtable, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {

    switch (param_pos) {
        case NAME:
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            propertyInfo.name = "name";
            break;

        case REPORT_ITEM:
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            propertyInfo.name = "reportitem";
            break;

        case REPORT_ID:
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS;
            propertyInfo.name = "reportid";
            break;
    }
}
}
```

### **Case 2:**

*data to send:*

```
<organization>
    <orgname>string</orgname>
    <address>sring</address>
    <users>
      <user>
         <name>string</name>
         <age>int</age>
         <Address>
            <addr1>string</addr1>
            <addr2>string</addr2>
         </Address>
      </user>
      <user>
         <name>string</name>
         <age>int</age>
         <Address>
            <addr1>string</addr1>
            <addr2>string</addr2>
         </Address>
      </user>
    </users>
</organization>
```

In this case I want to send this complex data to SOAP service through KvmSerializable object. Can any one help how can we make it through KvmSerializable...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to make objects: Address, User, Users and Organization all implementing KvmSerializable.

First start by making the object Address, because this is the most basic object. You can do this like you did in Case 1.

Then make the object User.

```
public class User implements KvmSerializable{

// The names of the variables, like they are defined in the WSDL
private static final String NAME = "name";
private static final String AGE = "age";
private static final String ADDRESS = "Address";

// DATA FIELDS
private String name;
private int age;
private Address address;

// KSOAP2 parsing methods
public Object getProperty(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return name;
    case 1:
        return age;
    case 2:
        return address;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 3;
}

public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index){
    case 0:
        name = value.toString();
        break;
    case 1:
        age = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 2:
        address = (Address)value;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index){
    case 0:
        info.name = NAME;
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        break;
    case 1:
        info.name = AGE;
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        break;
    case 2:
        info.name = ADDRESS;
        info.type = Adress.class;
        break;
    default:break;
    }
}
```

After this, make a Users object

```
public class Users implements KvmSerializable{

// The names of the variables, like they are defined in the WSDL
private static final String USER = "user";

// DATA FIELDS
private ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

// GETTERS & SETTERS
public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){
    return this.users;
}
public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> users){
    this.users = users;
}

// KSOAP2 parsing methods
public Object getProperty(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return users;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            users.add((User)value);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        info.type = User;
        info.name = USER;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you should create Organization the same way like User.

When sending the request, you should also register all the objects you use according to the WSDL.

```
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, OBJECT_NAME, CLASS);
```

I haven't tried this solution, so I'm not really sure if this is completely correct. I made this solution according to the way I have implemented something similar like this.

But I think you should try this an hopefully it will help you!

Comment: thank you for the reply... I have taken this as reference and made some changes to work the code peectly..